# New domain, new WordPress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, dns, installation, centos6

I am using Centos 6.7 with WordPress 4.6.1. I have one domain (gwbs.biz) that has an active WordPress installation. Now I have registered a new domain (jugurthine.cf) with its own WordPress installation (with a separate database).  The new domain is pointing to ns1.gwbs.biz/ns2.gwbs.biz and an IP address of 104.194.219.253 (the same configuration from gwbs.biz).  Apache automatically create the virtual host and DNS records for me. However, when I type in jugurthine.cf on the address bar, the domain is redirected to gwbs.biz. Is there something I am doing wrong? Should I get a separate virtual server?

Comment: they both are on same server?

Comment: Did you copy the database?  If so, Wordpress will force the old URL.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL